# Rails doesn't respect my select fields using includes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want write a query with active record and seems it never respect what I want to do. So, here are my example:

```
Phonogram.preload(:bpms).includes(:bpms).select("phonograms.id", "bpms.bpm")
```

This query returns all my fields from phonograms and bpms. The problem is that I need put more 15 relationships in this query.

I also tried use **joins** but didn't work properly. I've 10 phonograms and returns just 3.

Someone experienced that? How did you solve it properly?

Cheers.

Comment: try using `joins` instead of `includes`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady, I used. Query just returns phonograms with BPMS related. But, I've more relationships to put in this query, it will return just phonograms with related elements in all relationships. Doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0):

select with includes does not produce consistent behavior. It appears that if the included association returns no results, select will work properly, if it returns results, the select statement will have no effect. In fact, it will be completely ignored, such that your select statement could reference invalid table names and no error would be produced. select with joins will produce consistent behavior.
That's why you better go with joins like:

```
Phonogram.joins(:bpms).select("phonograms.id", "bpms.bpm")
```